# How to find text in a text file using tags?

Tags: c#, file, text, text-files

I have a file that I create from a C # code snippet, the structure of that text file is as follows:

```
#File
    
[ASSETS]
    
[VARIABLES]
i: 0
```

Then, in that same file, the following lines are written:

```
#File
    
[ASSETS]
   "Image.png">C:\Users\User\Desktop\Image.png
    "mine.gif"C:\Users\User\Desktop\mine.gif
    
[VARIABLES]
i: 0
```

Now what I want to do is find the text that is inside the tag "[ASSETS]" how do I do this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "write teh codez 4 me" site. A question is expected to include a good [mcve] that shows what you've tried already, along with a detailed explanation of what that code does, how that's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you need help with. As it stands now, your question is far too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone else mentioned, the file format you chose isn't *great* but working with what you decided, you could do something like this. Untested but I'll leave it up to you to fix any of my mistakes, ignore whitespace or blank lines, think of a more efficient solution, etc.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt"); //read file content 
int index = lines.IndexOf("[ASSETS]");//get index of assets tag
var assets = new List<string>(); // create variable to store asset lines
while (index != -1 && ++index < lines.Length && !lines[index].StartsWith("[")) // as long as we had found the assets tag, the next line exists, and the next line isn't a tag (presumably only lines that start with [ are tag lines...) then add the next line to your assets list
{
    assets.Add(lines[index]);
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, assets)); // demonstrate successful asset collection
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enable Singleline and Multiline, this regular expression should be able to do the job
`^\[ASSETS\](.+)^\[`
you'd find the string in the first capturing group

You can for example read more about C# regular expressions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)